# How to appropriately `$inject ` with parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

When I do not insert any parameters to `$inject` method, then it perfectly works:

```
(function()
    {        
       var FooController=function($scope){           
                     alert('a1');
                     debugger;
        };

        FooController.$inject=['$scope'];//it perfectly works            
        angular.module('someApp',[]).controller('FooController', FooController);
    }());
```

However, if I add some parameters to `$inject` method, then it does not work:

```
(function()
{   
    var FooController=function($scope, foo, bar) { 
                 alert('a1');
                 debugger;
    };

    var foo={type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
    var bar={type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};

    FooController.$inject=['$scope', 'foo', 'bar'];//it doesn't work
    angular.module('someApp',[]).controller('FooController', FooController);
}());
```

I've tried to put `alert('a1')`, but it is not run. So in my view, I declared the following row inappropriately:

```
FooController.$inject=['$scope', 'foo', 'bar'];//it doesn't work
```

Could you clarify what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: @Script47 Console does not show any error, browser just draws plain HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about creating dedicated `value` services?

```
(function()
{   
    var FooController=function($scope, foo, bar) { 
                 alert('a1');
                 debugger;
    };

    var foo={type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};
    var bar={type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};

    FooController.$inject=['$scope', 'foo', 'bar'];
    angular.module('someApp',[])
      .controller('FooController', FooController)
      .value('foo', foo)
      .value('bar', bar)
}());
```

Comment: You're cool! It works perfectly! But could you clarify why my approach does not work?

Comment: In order to perform injection, Angular needs to ask providers. By using value() we create them which is not the case with your initial code.